# TypeError: $(...).valid is not a function in jquery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

The below code is working fine on standalone but throwing javascript error when jsp is deployed on the server.I have included jquery.validation.js for .valid method.

```
 if (jQuery("input[name=uname]").valid()& jQuery("input[name=add]").valid() & jQuery("input[name=cty]").valid()& jQuery("input[name=stat]").valid()& jQuery("input[name=zip]").valid()& jQuery("input[name=ssn]").valid()& (jQuery('#Terms_Cond').is(":checked")))
```

Comment: AND operator in JS is `&&`

Comment: why are you manually checking all the fields in the first place?

Comment: & using binary AND operator to check all the conditions first and then return the value tru or false.

Answer (score 1):

Change & to &&, then try.

```
if (jQuery("input[name=uname]").valid()&& jQuery("input[name=add]").valid() && jQuery("input[name=cty]").valid()&& jQuery("input[name=stat]").valid()&& jQuery("input[name=zip]").valid()&& jQuery("input[name=ssn]").valid()&& (jQuery('#Terms_Cond').is(":checked")))
```

Comment: Thanks Edwin.But i have tried using && also.Checking all fields are done bcoz in the form I have some textboxs. On selecting the value from dropdown some of them has to be shown on page while others need to be hidden.So manual checking according to each dropdown value....